# Angular 6 @input value not showing up in HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

I have been wracking my brain on this for some time and cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I am somewhat of an Angular novice so it's extremely possible I could be doing something wrong that's really obvious. I have the following code:

**bucket.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div id="backButton">
        <a class="valign-wrapper" (click)="navigateBack()"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i> Back</a>
      </div>
      <h2 class="center-align" id="title">{{ name }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12" *ngFor="let object of objects">
      <app-bucket-file [key]="object.Key" [lastModified]="object.LastModified" [size]="object.Size" [owner]="object.Owner.DisplayName"></app-bucket-file>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**bucket-file.component.html**

```
<div class="card valign-wrapper">
  <div class="card-content white-text">
    <span class="card-title">{{ key }}</span>
    <p>Last Modified: {{ lastModified | date:'short' }}</p>
    <p>Size: {{ conversion(size, 2) }}</p>
    <p>Owner: {{ owner }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**bucket-file.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bucket-file',
  templateUrl: './bucket-file.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bucket-file.component.css']
})
export class BucketFileComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() key: string;
  @Input() lastModified: string;
  @Input() size: number;
  @Input() owner: string;
  public conversion = BucketFileComponent.bytesToSize;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Key:' + this.key);
  }

  public static bytesToSize(bytes: number, decimals: number) {
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB,', 'TB'];
    if (bytes === 0) {
      return '0 Bytes';
    }
    const k = 1024,
      dm = decimals <= 0 ? 0 : decimals || 2,
      i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
  }

}
```

The console.log works in **bucket-file.component.ts** ngOnInit() and returns the correct values, so I know that the input is working to some degree. However, when I try to display it in the template HTML I get nothing. No errors either. i am really confused as to what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz of your issue?

Comment: Is the background white? :-)

Comment: well its working onNgInit because you are initlializing it with the component, so load it into a variable in ngOnInit.. that will work

Answer (score 1):

I am such a derp. I had earlier moved the bucket-file into its own component, and neglected to move the css to the new component. Therefore, as one of the comments on my original post suggested, the background color was white, along with all the text colors being white too. It was all there I just couldn't see it.... smh

Comment: you should delete your question it hold no information value

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct.

1. **Are you sure the CSS class `card-title` isn't hiding your content?**

   To be sure, you can write:
     `<span class="card-title">Key : {{ key }}</span>`
2. What about the **other elements** *(lastModified ,...)*, **are they displayed**?
3. Also, in your `bucket.component.html` component you can write:

      `<div class="col s12" *ngFor="let object of objects">
         Key: {{ object.Key }}
         <app-bucket-file ... ></app-bucket-file>
       </div>`

   To be sure **the key is not changed or removed by something else** *(after being displayed in `ngOnInit()` of the child component)*.